# Interactive plot using Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

[QQ plot for fitted distribution s][have tried several distributions to fit on data. For goodness of fit test using emperical and theoretical quantitle plot but i want that plot using Plotly. I am attaching a image , i want to convert that into Plotly]

[image: QQ plot]

Comment: Hi Prabha, can we get the code used to generate this image?

Comment: Example data would help significantly.